# Do I need to use a vuex for recording markup data?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I use vuex state only for containing **user data**. Do I need to store data property that contain **opened or closed panel**?

Below there is a piece of code..

```
const state = {
user: {
    id: -1,
    name: '',
    authenticated: false,
    avatar_url: '',
},
```

and markup

```
<h5 class="text-subhead-2 text-light">Some text</h5>
    <div v-for="elem in elements" class="panel panel-default open" data-z="0.5">
                 //list of elements below
```

or I can use vuex reactivity for all my requirements?

Comment: In general, store stuff in Vuex if it's needed by more than one component. Store it in the component's `data` if it's only needed by that component. In this case, non-Vuex is probably correct.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst @ceejayoz has a valid point in the comments, I'd like to offer one other angle as to how we could *view* (pun intended) this.

I don't know the scale of your application, but as "opened/closed" is a flag (a state), then Vuex seems a fine place for it. Maybe one day you'd like to start tracking some (any) interactions or other components would become dependent on a panel's closed/open state. Then instead of having the panel component emit events, other components or trackers could simply keep an eye on the state (Vuex).

Now, there's always the [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it) principle and that's why I brought up the application scale. But I've set up all my Vue apps with a sort of state manager, since it makes component-to-component communication later down the road a breeze. Another point in the favour of Vuex is that it's already part of your project, so it's not even a question of integrating it, just extending it for your app's internal state as well.